# What is the gradient of a vector with respect to a vector?

Tags: calculus, vectors

This might be a pretty embarrassing question but I am trying to find the gradient of:

$$f^*(x) = 
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
C^T_1 g \\
\vdots \\
C^T_j g\\
\vdots \\
C^T_K g
\end{array}
\right)$$

where $C^T_j = [C_{1,j}, ... , C_{k,j}, ..., C_{K,j}] \in \mathbb{R}^{D \times K} $ and $g \in \mathbb{R}^k $.

Intuitively, I was trying to compute the change of the above function with respect to one of the vectors $C_j$ or would it make more sense to consider the change of that function when only one of the $C_{k,j}$ changed? i.e.

$$ \frac{\partial f^*(x)}{\partial C_{j,k}}$$

instead of:

$$ \bigtriangledown  f^*(x)$$

I did try looking at the definition of derivatives form math cookbook:

[image]

but didn't quite understand which one I was suppose to use.

Comment: Gradient is a vector of derivatives of multivariable **scalar** function. But you have **vector** function here. What you're trying to find is Jacobi matrix really. That's the first remark. The second is that rule from matrix cookbook doesn't help much because it has no context (you're applying it to particular kind of formula).

Comment: Also, please, clean up your notation: $f^\ast$ is a function of $x$ but it doesn't appear anywhere in its definition. Also $C^T_j$ doesn't have the same second dimension as $g$.

Comment: Maybe it would help if you back up a step or two and explain where this function comes from and why you need its "gradient".

Comment: sure I will update in a bit, sorry for the typos. Btw, that is the definition of f, given any x, it outputs that vector, with the caveat that I forgot to mention that g is a function of x. I didn't realize it had so many typos. Give me a moment.